# how to display ref name after user click the link?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

lets say I have the link http://localhost:8080/Simple/index.php?ref=user5 after I click it, I want "user5" to show up inside Input.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try to use $_GET['ref']?
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: show us your code. What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You must use $_GET variable to access URL variable.

here is a simple solution:

```
<input type='text' name='foe' id='bar' value='<?php echo $_GET['ref']; ?>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php inbuilt GET method which helps to get or collect query string parameters from URL.
http://localhost:8080/Simple/index.php?ref=user5

Once you click this URL then get query string parameters through $_GET, because $_GET is an associative array so you can achieve **user5** by $_GET['ref'].